# How get : merge_request_iid if know CI_BUILD_ID and CI_PROJECT_ID?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I want to create Job trigged by
MERGE_REQUEST and exist
force_remove_source_branch in true.

Get info about force_remove_source_branch from api

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${API_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "$CI_GITLAB/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS/changes" | jq -r ".force_remove_source_branch"
```

For gitlab api need CI_PROJECT_ID and CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS

```
CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS is merge_request_iid
```

I research much pipeline

**CI_PROJECT_ID exist its OK**

But I couldn't find **merge_request_iid** in clean variant.
Only must symantec variant

```
WD=/builds/projects/adv/ETL/mvp
See merge request projects/adv/ETL/mvp!18
```

How simple get :merge_request_iid from pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a set of CI Variables that exist for Merge Request Pipelines in the [Predefined Variables Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines).

Specifically the `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` variable is a Predefined Variable when the Pipeline Source (`$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`) is `merge_request_event`, so as long as the job runs for [Merge Requests pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html), this variable will exist.

Here's an example job for a Merge Request pipeline:

```yaml
Example Job:
  stage: example
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE === 'merge_request_event'
      when: always
    - when: never
  script:
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID # prove that the Merge Request IID exists
    - curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${API_ACCESS_TOKEN}" "$CI_GITLAB/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/changes" | jq -r ".force_remove_source_branch"
```

When a job has a rules section that looks somewhat like this for the `merge_request_event` source, the job will run for [Merge Request Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html).